# Not able to understand working of Cors in my Node js serverside code

Tags: node.js, cors

The below is my server.js code of my React app's backend.

I am not able to understand the working of the below line

```
app.use(cors(options));
```

**The full code is as below:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
let allowed = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4000"];
function options(req, res) {
  let tmp;
  let origin = req.header("Origin");
  if (allowed.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
    tmp = {
      origin: true,
      optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    };
  } else {
    tmp = {
      origin: false,
    };
  }
  res(null, tmp);
}

app.use(cors(options));
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server running at 8000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hi From server hello super");
});
```

**My doubt**

1. The "options" is a function which has arguments . But in the line app.use(cors(options)), how the arguments are passed
2. res(null,tmp) -> what does it do. Is it equivalent to res.send(tmp)?

Answer (score -1):

This is using the [Express-CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors-asynchronously) which has some documentation describing what it means to have `options` be a function.

Specifically, the `options` function is called by the middleware as the request is being processed to determine the impact on the specified fields like `origin`, `method`, `optionsSuccessStatus` (by the way, your code has a typo for this field—its missing an `s`), etc.

As the documentation shows, `res` is just a callback that lets the rest of the middleware and other middlewares continue normal execution.